# Main difference between HashMap and ConcurrentHashMap in the case of non-select operation?

Tags: java

As per my knowledge while performing non-select operation in `HashMap` and `ConcurrentHashMap` , the `ConcurrentHashMap` blocks the entire `Segments`(by default-16)?

Comment: What is a 'non-select operation'?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that `HashMap` is not **thread-safe**, which means that if you have several threads using it you need to take care of concurrent operations yourself. You can easily make it thread-safe using `Collections.synchronizedMap(map)` which creates a **wrapper object**, in which all methods are `synchronized` (on that wrapper object) and delegate to the wrapped map. As you can figure out this means poor performance as only one thread (reader or writer doesn't matter) has access to it.

As you pointed out `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread-safe and tries to handle synchronization a bit differently than `Collections.synchronizedMap()`. Instead of a single lock it tries to use multiple locks by partitioning the underlying map into **buckets** and having a lock per bucket. With that several threads can use the map concurrently without problems as they might be working on records in different buckets. In this case you don't need to lock the whole map (all buckets) but only the bucket in which the record you are interested in resides, which means that you can perform a parallel operation on all buckets at the same time. Obviously if all threads are working on the same record (or the same bucket) they will still be synchronized like in `Collections.synchronizedMap()` and will be blocked on writes. This approach is really good when the number of your reader threads outnumbers writer threads.

For instance you might have (very simplified):

```
ConcurrentHashMap = [ bucket1 = [r1->x], bucket2 = [r2->y], bucket3 = [r3, z] ]
```

When you are doing a read/write operation for entry with key **r1** the map will choose **bucket1** as that record should be there and lock bucket1 and only bucket1. Then when another thread comes if it queries for **r2** it can safely do so but if it queries for **r1** also it has to wait as bucket1 is locked.

Of course there's a performance penalty behind all of this but it's not terribly high (although I don't have any benchmarks to back this statement).

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

No,In case of non select(EX. put) operation also,Lock is always taken at the segment level.

You can see the ConcurrentHashMap source code.

Whenever you call put() method on concurrent hashmap it first calculate hash position for the particular segment,then calls trylock() method on that segment only, not at the table level.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurentHashMap has different structure than simple HashMap.
A ConcurrentHashMap is divided into number of segments (16 by default) on initialization.

It allows similar number of threads to access these segments concurrently so that each thread work on a specific segment.

While one thread is working on one segment it puts a lock on it. It does not block the rest of the segments.

If you want to read more about it, I suggest link below - good explanation with clear examples

[Link](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/14/popular-hashmap-and-concurrenthashmap-interview-questions/)